# Eclipse and Apache checkstyle plugin alignment

Tags: checkstyle

In Spring Boot project, I am using apache checkstyle plugin in POM as shown below:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
                <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>                    
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In Eclipse Neon.1 Release (4.6.1), I have installed Eclipse CheckStyle plugin from below path:

[Eclipse CheckStyle Plugin](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/#!/)

After fixing all Check Style issues highlighted by Eclipse plugin, when i run validate goal of maven, I still see many check style violations on the console related to import dependency reported by Maven plugin e.g.

```
D:\Data\Filter.java:4: warning: 'com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext' should be separated from previous import group.
D:\Data\Filter.java:39: warning: Import statement for 'org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value' is in the wrong order. Should be in the 'THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE' group, expecting not assigned imports on this line.
```

I want to know why eclipse plugin has not highlighted these issues while Maven plugin has reported them despite the fact both are using google_checks.xml. How to align them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maven-checkstyle-plugin` by default uses an older version of Checkstyle.
See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/history.html (it lists 6.11.2 with `maven-checkstyle-plugin` version 2.17)

Depending on what version of Eclipse-CS you have installed, you could be running with 2 different versions of Checkstyle as Eclipse-CS tries to use newer versions, but may not use the latest.
Their website states:

> Latest release 8.0.0, based on Checkstyle 8.0

To change the version of Checkstyle `maven-checkstyle-plugin` uses, see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html .